# What does "bank" mean in banked oval track?

Tags: meaning

Google gives a definition about *roller derbies*

> a team skating competition on roller skates, held on a *banked* oval track.

where "bank" is used as a verb.

Cambridge dictionary gives definitions about *bank* as a verb.

> to keep your money in a particular bank, or to put money into a bank
>
> (of an aircraft) to fly with one wing higher than the other when turning
>
> to collect in or form into a mass, or to make something do this

None of them makes sense to me, so what does "bank" mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [banked turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banked_turn) is when a corner is sloped [like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/WinchesterSpeedwayTurn.jpg) to facilitate higher cornering speeds, usually on racetracks.

Comment: Likely this *bank* is the same word as in *river bank*.